Simplify the condition to read partitioned data
I have a delta table partitioned by year,month,day. partitioned columns are set as string.
I need to read data for the last seven days from the Delta table. For instance, if the job runs on a Tuesday, it should retrieve data from the previous Monday to Sunday, totaling seven days. Is there a way I can simplify this, ensure we read only partitioned columns instead of concatenating them?
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

trigger_date = "2024-05-07" # yyyy-mm-dd
trigger_date_obj = datetime.strptime(trigger_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
start_date_obj = trigger_date_obj - timedelta(days=8)
end_date_obj = trigger_date_obj - timedelta(days=2)

# Extract week, start_day and end_day
start_day = start_date_obj.day
start_month = start_date_obj.month
start_year = start_date_obj.year

end_day = end_date_obj.day
end_month = end_date_obj.month
end_year = end_date_obj.year

if start_day < end_day and trigger_date_obj.month == end_date_obj.month and start_date_obj.year == end_date_obj.year:
    # Case 1: Trigger Week days within the same month and year
    condition = ((col("year") == year) & 
                      (col("month") == month) & 
                      (col("day").between(start_day, end_day)) 
                     )
elif start_day < end_day and trigger_date_obj.month != end_date_obj.month and start_date_obj.year == end_date_obj.year:
    # Case 2: For ex: Apr-2, start day mar-25 and end day : mar-31
    date_condition = ((col("year") == year) & 
                      ((col("month") == start_date_obj.month) & 
                       (col("day").between(start_day, end_day))) 
                     )
elif start_day < end_day and start_date_obj.year != end_date_obj.year:
    # Case 3: Week spanning two years, data from the previous year. ie Schdule is 02-Jan,read Dec 25-31 data
    date_condition = ((col("year") == str(int(year) - 1)) & 
                      (col("month") == "12") & 
                      (col("day").between(25, 31))
                     )
elif start_day > end_day and start_date_obj.year == end_date_obj.year:
    # Case 4: Week spanning two months within the same year
    date_condition = ((col("year") == year) & 
                      (((col("month") == start_date_obj.month) & 
                        (col("day").between(start_day, 31))) | 
                       ((col("month") == end_date_obj.month) & 
                        (col("day").between(1, end_day)))) 
                     )
else:
    # Case 5: Week spanning two months and two years
    date_condition = ((((col("year") == start_date_obj.year) & 
                       (col("month") == start_date_obj.month) & 
                       (col("day").between(start_day, 31))) | 
                      ((col("year") == end_date_obj.year) & 
                       (col("month") == end_date_obj.month) & 
                       (col("day").between(1, end_day)))) 
                     )


data = spark.read.format("delta").table("delta_table_name") 
data = data.filter(condition)




for simplicity and readability, i think you should consider converting your partitioned column(s) to a DateType, repartitioning, and then using .between(start_date_obj, end_date_obj). it feels like you're reinventing the wheel by breaking down dates in this format
